# comparing 2 functions with big O notation

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

The question is :

Assume that f, g: N → N are functions such that f(n)=O(logn) and g(n) = Ω(nlogn).
Is it possible that f(n) = Ω(g(n))?

I'm thinking that it is not possible becaouse nlogn > logn, not sure if it's true nor how to proove it.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Let's assume it's possible:

- `g(n) = Ω(nlogn)` ==> there is `a` such that `g(n) > anlogn` for a sufficiently large `n`.
- `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` ==> there is `b` such that `f(n) > bg(n) > banlogn` for a sufficiently large `n`.
- Let `c = ab` ==> `f(n) > cnlogn` for a sufficiently large `n` ==> `f(n) = Ω(nlogn)`.
- `f(n) = O(logn)` ==> there is `d` such that `f(n) < dlogn` for a sufficiently large `n`.
- ==> `cnlogn < f(n) < dlogn` ==> `cnlogn < dlogn` ==> `n < d/c`. That's not possible since natural number `n` exists which is larger than `d/c`. ==> contradiction to the initial assumption.